# perl get all message headers from imap message

Tags: perl, imap

I use [`Mail::IMAPClient`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::IMAPClient)

Have some variables

```
$body = $imap->body_string($msg);
$header = $imap->message_string($msg);
```

$body contains body of message, but $header contains header and body of message. I have not found a method in IMAPClient, who get only message header.

I need delete body from $header. Split $body and $header bad variant, because body can be very big. Body and header separates the empty string, but I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at http://gagravarr.org/code/test-imap-headers.pl

It suggests the [`Mail::IMAPClient`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::IMAPClient) package supports/supported the 'keyword' "ALL" to get all headers at once:

```perl
my %headers = %{ $imap->parse_headers( $msg, "ALL" ) };
for my $h ( keys %headers ) {
    my @hdrs = @{ $headers{$h} };
    print "$h (" . scalar @hdrs . " entries)\n";
    foreach (@hdrs) { print "\t$_\n"; }
}
```

Comment: I try "ALL", but I returned hash. In this way, works almost like I need. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Btw: in the snippet you see an iteration through that hash (at the bottom)

Comment: I see, I mean that tried "ALL" before and did not know how to make a hash of what I need.

Comment: Can you put the relevant parts of the code into the answer? This is pretty close to a link-only answer, which is frowned upon.