# Perl: how to remove all after first blank line?

Tags: regex, perl

I have some string and i need remove all after first blank line in this string.

i tried use this 
`$string = ~s/\^\s*$.*//` 
but this expression delete all characters in string!

Comment: `= ~` is not the binding operator `=~`, it is `=` assignment operator and `~` bitwise negation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

- `\h` to match horizontal spacing,
- `\n` to match a newline
- `/m` Modifier to allow `^` to match on any line
- `/s` Modifier so the any character will match newlines

As demonstrated:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = do {local $/; <DATA>};

$string =~ s/^\h*\n.*//ms;

print $string;

__DATA__
Hello World
Second Line

New Paragraph
another line
final line
```

Outputs:

```
Hello World
Second Line
```

#### Addendum

To separate a header from body, just use `split`.

Technically, the pattern should just be `/\n\n/`, but given context of your question, I'd recommend:

```
my ($header, $body) = split /\n\h*\n/, $string, 2;
```

Comment: It's work in new file, but not work in my code.
My last question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037882/perl-get-all-message-headers-from-imap-message)
The answer is not suitable for me, because the handler needs the original headers of messages.
$header = $imap->message_string($msg);
Body and header separates the empty line.

Comment: Then just use `split` like in my addendum.

Comment: Thx, this work with split, but i but I do not understand why do not work construction `$string =~ s/^\h*\n.*//ms;` and my `$string =~ s/\^\s*$.*//`

Comment: Well, you're regex is trying to use a literal carot `\^` instead of the regex symbol for start of a line `^`.  Additionally, you're not using the `/m` Modifier which changes the meaning of both `^` and `$` to match on any line.  Also, \s* will match newlines.  And without the `/s` Modifier, the any character will not match newlines.  There are some of the issues with your approach.